# Is the a way to enable node.js REPL terminal color with vim-key-binding?

Tags: node.js, key-bindings, read-eval-print-loop

Running `node` in terminal will bring you into its REPL mode, with syntax highlighting (e.g. `number` is yellow, while `string` is green).

However, I'm not comfortable with it's default `emacs-key-binding`, so I follow some suggestion:

```
alias node='env NODE_NO_READLINE=1 rlwrap node'
```

This works great, I get `vim-key-binding`, but the `syntax highlighter` is disabled.

---

So I give a second try:

```
alias node='rlwrap -a node'
```

This time I get both `vim-key-binding` and `syntax highlighter` work out, but the are some bug e.g. when I type this into REPL mode:

```
> [1,2,3]
```

the output is correct (with **syntax highlighting**)

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

but the input line from above has changed to

```
> [1,[1,2,3]
```

This bug is more annoying than having no `syntax highlight`.

---

Any idea to make this 2 things work well together?

P.S. I don't need tab-compilation (at least for this time).